# Geth Error: could not decrypt key with given passphrase

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, geth

While following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/shokone/https-medium-com-shokone-building-a-hello-world-smart-contract-on-ethereum-f303c7d05f0) I ran into an error message.  After inputting `personal.unlockAccount(eth.accounts[0])` I am asked for my password.  Once entered the Geth console gives me `Error: could not decrypt key with given passphrase`.  I know that the password is correct and some [googling](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/15282) suggests that the error message text may be wrong.  It seems it may be the case that my newly created account doesn't have enough ETH yet but, if this is the case, how can we know how much we need to be able to unlock an account?

Comment: The "googling" you linked to seems completely unrelated. Generally, this error would truly mean that the password you entered is wrong. You definitely don't need to have any ether in an account to decrypt it.

Answer (score 1):

Well this error message is  propagated only when you have entered your passphrase incorrectly.

As specified by @smarx,the google link you have attached seems to be unrelated to your issue.

Comment: Indeed, this is the case.  Despite being asked to create a password and asked to confirm it I find that simply hitting enter when asked for that same password unlocks the account.

Comment: @lola_the_coding_girl please add your discovery as the correct answer - this is precisely what just happened to me

Comment: after reading a bit further it appears that it's asking for the account password, not the passphrase, and that we don't set that initially

Comment: Thank you @lola_the_coding_girl just hitting enter and NOT entering the passphrase is the trick. I would really appreciate if you would answers your own question.